# Office 365 - how to manage many users

Tags: security, powershell, office365

I have 200 unsorted users in office 365. I want to find an easy way to manage who they are and what security group each user belongs to.

Is there an easy way to export username and what groups each user belongs to?

Iam quite new to poweshell...
But i want to export a CSV file with user and gruops.

Is this possible?

Or do you recommend any other way to quick get an overview of all users and what grups they belong to.

Some users need to be in multiple groups and i suspect some users are missing in groups they should be in..

Thanks for any tips i can get.

Answer (score 1):

```
################################################################################################################################################################ 
# Script accepts 2 parameters from the command line 
# 
# Office365Username - Optional - Administrator login ID for the tenant we are querying 
# Office365Password - Optional - Administrator login password for the tenant we are querying 
# 
# 
# To run the script 
# 
# .\Get-DistributionGroupMembers.ps1 [-Office365Username admin@xxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com] [-Office365Password Password123]
# 
# 
# Author:                 Alan Byrne 
# Version:                 2.0 
# Last Modified Date:     16/08/2014 
# Last Modified By:     Alan Byrne alan@cogmotive.com 
################################################################################################################################################################ 

#Accept input parameters 
Param( 
    [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$false, ValueFromPipeline=$true)] 
    [string] $Office365Username, 
    [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$false, ValueFromPipeline=$true)] 
    [string] $Office365Password 
) 

#Constant Variables 
$OutputFile = "DistributionGroupMembers.csv"   #The CSV Output file that is created, change for your purposes 
$arrDLMembers = @{} 


#Remove all existing Powershell sessions 
Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession 

#Did they provide creds?  If not, ask them for it.
if (([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Office365Username) -eq $false) -and ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Office365Password) -eq $false))
{
    $SecureOffice365Password = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Office365Password -Force     

    #Build credentials object 
    $Office365Credentials  = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $Office365Username, $SecureOffice365Password 
}
else
{
    #Build credentials object 
    $Office365Credentials  = Get-Credential
}
#Create remote Powershell session 
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://ps.outlook.com/powershell -Credential $Office365credentials -Authentication Basic –AllowRedirection         

#Import the session 
Import-PSSession $Session -AllowClobber | Out-Null          

#Prepare Output file with headers 
Out-File -FilePath $OutputFile -InputObject "Distribution Group DisplayName,Distribution Group Email,Member DisplayName, Member Email, Member Type" -Encoding UTF8 

#Get all Distribution Groups from Office 365 
$objDistributionGroups = Get-DistributionGroup -ResultSize Unlimited 

#Iterate through all groups, one at a time     
Foreach ($objDistributionGroup in $objDistributionGroups) 
{     

    write-host "Processing $($objDistributionGroup.DisplayName)..." 

    #Get members of this group 
    $objDGMembers = Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $($objDistributionGroup.PrimarySmtpAddress) 

    write-host "Found $($objDGMembers.Count) members..." 

    #Iterate through each member 
    Foreach ($objMember in $objDGMembers) 
    { 
        Out-File -FilePath $OutputFile -InputObject "$($objDistributionGroup.DisplayName),$($objDistributionGroup.PrimarySMTPAddress),$($objMember.DisplayName),$($objMember.PrimarySMTPAddress),$($objMember.RecipientType)" -Encoding UTF8 -append 
        write-host "`t$($objDistributionGroup.DisplayName),$($objDistributionGroup.PrimarySMTPAddress),$($objMember.DisplayName),$($objMember.PrimarySMTPAddress),$($objMember.RecipientType)"
    } 
} 

#Clean up session 
Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession
```

Comment: That script works great.  It exports a csv with groups and members.